# Options for Py_BuildValue when creating handle

Tags: python, c

Which options should I use for Py_BuildValue when I am trying to return PyObject which is handle at C?

From Leddar SDK: "Returns "The handle to pass to other Leddar* functions." this handle I would need to return to python code.

Comment: In the C code I have defined it as a global variable

     static LeddarHandle gHandle=NULL;

And set it with:

     gHandle = LeddarCreate();

Comment: Just found out that in the header file that Handle is defined like this

    typedef void *LeddarHandle;